# Cumulative Summation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm writing a query, part of Stored Procedure in SQL Server. I need to find cumulative summation in SQL Server.

A variable will hold a integer value say `100`. Let's say

```
Declare @Variable int = 100
```

Now the `@NewVariable` will have below formula:

```
@NewVariable = @Variable * (1 - 0.005)
```

Hence `@NewVariable = 99.5`

Now, the `@NewestVariable` will have below formula;

```
@NewestVariable = @NewVariable * (1 - 0.005)
```

Hence the `@NewestVariable` will have value of `99.00`

Likewise this calculation will occur 24 times and all the results will be sum at the end.

Hence final result will be: 100 + 99.5 +99.00 + .... ...

I tried to achieve the desired result using @Count Variable (`DECLARE @COUNT INT = 24`) and using a While loop, but I'm not sure whether I'm correct or not?

Request your help!

Thanks!

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried. Also, it looks like a simple mathematic problem - doesn't it ? A summation of series ?

Comment: it's hard to tell if it's correct or not unless you show your actual code

Comment: @SuyashKhandwe: Yeah It is summation of series

Comment: @user1455836: Code sharing isn't allowed. Though let me share some test code

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a CTE as below:

```
declare @variable int = 100
;with cte as
(
 select convert(numeric(8,2), @variable) as var, 1 as recCount
 union all
 select convert(numeric(8,2), @variable * (1 - recCount*0.005)) as var, recCount+1 as recCount 
 from cte
 where recCount < 24
)
select sum(var) as total from cte
```

[**Working Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/28215)

**Edit:** Adjusted to resolve rounding error as per @peter.petrov 's comment

If you need to get the values of each row before counting, please use **[this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/28218)**

Comment: This gives too much of a rounding error, I think. Not sure if it matters.

Comment: @peter.petrov: Thanks for the comment, I have adjusted to resolve the rounding issue.

Comment: Actually re-reading the question maybe that's what the OP needed because he wrote: 100 + 99.5 + 99.00. Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
declare @Variable decimal(20,10);
set @Variable = 100;

declare @Sum decimal(20,10);
set @Sum = 0;

declare @cnt int;
set @cnt = 1;

while (@cnt <= 24) 
begin
    set @Sum = @Sum + @Variable;
    set @Variable = @Variable * (1.0 - 0.005);
    set @cnt = @cnt + 1;
end;

select @Sum;
```

Comment: Are your sure this is wrong - 
`DECLARE @Variable INT = 100 ?`
**Try this -**
`DECLARE @Variable INT = 100
SELECT @Variable`

Comment: @SuyashKhandwe I removed that part, I was wrong that it was wrong ;)

Comment: Downvote was for wrong info about syntax - you reverted - I reverted.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer would be like this

```
DECLARE @Variable INT = 100
SELECT @Variable
DECLARE @counter INT = 1
DECLARE @SumVariable NUMERIC(20,2) = @Variable
DECLARE @NewVariable NUMERIC(20,2) = @Variable

WHILE(@counter<24)
BEGIN
    SET @NewVariable = @NewVariable * 0.995
    SET @SumVariable = @SumVariable + @NewVariable
    SET @counter = @counter+1
END
SELECT @SumVariable
```

Comment: This will be executed 23 times, not 24, I think.

Comment: No 23 should give you the correct result since the sum variable starts from the value of the variable itself

Comment: @peter.petrov - Its the simplified for of the equation asked in the question. The commeneted part of the code in the answer above explains how it is deduced. You can check by replacing 24 by 2. Also, this could any be replaced with any of the commented line to work just the same

Comment: The code is fine. I just mean 1.995 should be 0.995, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a ["quirky update"](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals) to avoid while-loops. If you're not interesed in intermediate resuls, just modify the last code line to select only the `max(total)`.

```
DECLARE @total DECIMAL(10,3) = 0.000

;WITH "data" AS
(
    SELECT CAST( 100 AS DECIMAL(10,3)) AS id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST( id * ( 1 - 0.005 ) AS DECIMAL(10,3)) FROM "data" WHERE id > 100 * (1 - 21 * 0.005)
)
SELECT 
    id, total = CAST( 0.000 AS DECIMAL(10,3))
INTO #temp
FROM 
    "data" 
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 23 );

UPDATE t SET @total = total = @total + id FROM #temp t

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

See [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/28229/1) for testing.